# Ruby cannot load such file --ftools (Load Error)

Tags: ruby

I'm a complete Ruby newbie and all I want to do is just run a legacy ruby script (that too an open source one by Erik Veenstra). I have a Windows batch script that runs it basically that I am trying to execute. I installed Ruby on my computer, allowed it to set paths, and I tried to run it and here's the error I got:

```
I:/2011/devl/3rdparty/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- ftools (LoadError)
        from I:/2011/devl/3rdparty/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Users/<blah>/AppData/Local/Temp/tar2rubyscript.d.6692.1/rubyscript2exe/ev/ftools.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from I:/2011/devl/3rdparty/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from I:/2011/devl/3rdparty/ruby/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Users/<blah>/AppData/Local/Temp/tar2rubyscript.d.6692.1/rubyscript2exe/init.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from I:/2011/devl/path/to/<myrbsrc>/trunk/bin/../src/rubyscript2exe.rb:627:in `load'
        from I:/2011/devl/path/to/<myrbsrc>/trunk/bin/../src/rubyscript2exe.rb:627:in `block in <main>'
        from I:/2011/devl/path/to/<myrbsrc>/trunk/bin/../src/rubyscript2exe.rb:577:in `block in newlocation'
        from I:/2011/devl/path/to/<myrbsrc>/trunk/bin/../src/rubyscript2exe.rb:505:in `block in newlocation'
        from I:/2011/devl/path/to/<myrbsrc>/trunk/bin/../src/rubyscript2exe.rb:472:in `newlocation'
        from I:/2011/devl/path/to/<myrbsrc>/trunk/bin/../src/rubyscript2exe.rb:505:in `newlocation'
        from I:/2011/path/to/<myrbsrc>/trunk/bin/../src/rubyscript2exe.rb:577:in `newlocation'
        from I:/2011/devl/path/to/<myrbsrc>/trunk/bin/../src/rubyscript2exe.rb:619:in `<main>'
```

Appreciate any ideas on how to resolve this! If it helps I can post the source Ruby code.

Comment: Change `ftools` in the script to `fileutils`.

Comment: Which script are you talking about? I did a search for "ftools" recursively everywhere in the source and it didn't find it. Any further ideas?

Comment: I see. Well, from your log, I can see that some part of rubyscript2exe called `ftools.rb` is trying to require itself. I think Ruby might just refuse to do that.

Comment: I noticed in the source is a line (pointed to by the log) as doing: if File.file?("./init.rb") load File.expand_path("./init.rb") else; and the errors seem to be coming from some generated file in C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Temp\... (as specified in the log). But after the build is done, the temp file is gone! Any clues there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the source code I had is a lot older and even after getting the latest version, it had issues. But knowing that it worked at some point, I proceeded to install an older version of Ruby on Windows (1.8.7-p358) and everything works fine then and I was able to build and get my executable. Anyway, not the most elegant solution. But if anybody knows of a fix for rubyscript2exe with the latest Windows version of Ruby, please reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

use

> require "fileutils"

instead because ftools is not supported with ruby-1.9.x

Comment: When you say "not supported with ruby-1.9.x", do you mean "not supported with ruby-1.9.x and older", or "not supported with ruby-1.9.x and newer"?