# cannot load such file -- ftools in ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails

I am using solr:sunspot gem. when I tried to run 'rake sunspot:reindex', its throwing '
rake aborted! cannot load such file -- ftools' error.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552524/ruby-cannot-load-such-file-ftools-load-error

Comment: @Pavan,I have checked that post, but no use. My problem still exist.

Comment: are you using RVM or rbenv or any other ruby version tools? Which version of the gem have you got installed?

Comment: @Mikey, I am using RVM and i installed rsolr 1.0.6
sunspot 1.2.1
sunspot_rails 1.2.1